increasing sequence of subgroups determine the original group
I'm currently trying to characterize the group $G$ by its proper subgroups. I believe that the following statement is true, but fail to prove it.
Let $G, H$ be groups, $G_1, G_2, \ldots$ be an increasing sequence of subgroups of $G$, and $H_1, H_2, \ldots$ be an increasing sequence of subgroups of $H$. If $G_n\cong H_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}G_n=G$ and $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}H_n=H$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $H$.
I know that this is true if the maps $G_n\rightarrow G_{n+1}\cong H_{n+1}$ and $G_n\cong H_n \rightarrow H_{n+1}$ are the same, but I am unsure whether a counterexample exists where this condition does not hold.
Could someone provide a proof or a counterexample to this conjecture?

It's not true*. For every prime $p$ consider the abelian group $A_p = \mathbb{Z}[1/p]$, which is an increasing union of subgroups isomorphic to the integers, namely $\langle 1/p^n \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}$. But these groups are pairwise non-isomorphic since $q A_p = A_p$ iff $p = q$ for primes $ p,q$.
Even $\mathbb{Q}$ can be written this way. And if you also allow increasing sequences that are not strictly increasing, we can just take $\mathbb{Z}$ of course.
*There is no reason why it should hold when we have no compatibility relations between the isomorphisms. Also please notice that "conjecture" refers to a mathematical statement which is likely to be true but hard to prove even for professionals. So this term doesn't fit here.

(+1) for the maths.  Strongly disagree about the word "conjecture".  Anyone can make a conjecture.  Many religious texts apply a negative connotation to the word.  That is they refer to things as conjecture precisely when they claim there is no good reason to believe they are plausible.  You could argue that within mathematics the word has a different meaning to in general use (e.g. group, ring, field, scheme), but I see no evidence, and am much happier when students refer to claims they cannot prove as conjecture, than when they just state them and hope they will get the benefit of the doubt.

It's based on my experience how the word is used in mathematics. Many years ago I gave a small talk at university where I mentioned a "conjecture" I have  been working on, and the whole crowd cringed. It was just a problem I was looking at. (Eventually it turned to a theorem which got published and cited a lot, but at that point, that wasn't clear at all.)

I see - in the context of a research talk I see what you mean.  In a courtroom it is the opposite (a suggestion that the statement is not reliable), and in a classroom I think neutral.

@MartinBrandenburg It was more simple example than I thought it would be. Thank you for your answer and correcting my use of words.
